# How to show image on hover over org chart

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, orgchart

I am writing below code to create org chart using Jquery plugin reference as below

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Fully-Customizable-Organisational-Chart-Plugin-With-jQuery-OrgChart/

It shows image on hover on different nodes like below

[image]

I referred this plugin and written code to create org chart which pick Sharepoint source and create org chart hierarchy nodes like below

[image]

Org chart is working as expected and content as well coming what am not getting is image on hover below is my full code

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'/>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/2.1.9/css/jquery.orgchart.min.css'/> 
<style>

.orgchart {
    box-sizing: border-box!important;
    display: inline-block!important;
    min-height: 202px!important;
    min-width: 202px!important;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none!important;
    -webkit-user-select: none!important;
    -khtml-user-select: none!important;
    -moz-user-select: none!important;
    -ms-user-select: none!important;
    user-select: none!important;
    background-image: none !important;
    background-size: 10px 10px!important;
    border: 1px dashed transparent;
    padding: 20px!important;
}

.orgchart .lines .leftLine {
    border-left: 1px solid #eb3c96!important;
    float: none!important;
    border-radius: 0!important;
}

.orgchart .lines .topLine {
    border-top: 2px solid #eb3c96!important;
}

.orgchart .node .title {
    box-sizing: border-box!important;
    padding: 2px!important;
    width: 130px!important;
    text-align: center!important;
    font-size: .75rem!important;
    font-weight: 700!important;
    height: 20px!important;
    overflow: hidden!important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis!important;
    white-space: nowrap!important;
    background-color: #eb3c96!important;
    color: #fff!important;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0!important;
}


.orgchart .lines .downLine {
    background-color: #eb3c96!important;
    margin: 0 auto!important;
    height: 20px!important;
    width: 2px!important;
    float: none!important;
}

</style>
<div id="chart-container"></div>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/2.1.9/js/jquery.orgchart.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Employee (ID,Name,Manager,Designation,Email) {
    this.ID = ID;
    this.Name= Name;
    this.Manager = Manager;
    this.Designation = Designation;
    this.Email=Email;
}
function GetOrgJSON(employeeList,manager){
    var note = '';
    var employeeProcessed=[];
    for(var i=0;i<employeeList.length;i++){
        var objEmp = employeeList[i];      
        if(objEmp.Manager == manager && employeeProcessed.indexOf(objEmp.Name) < 0 ){
            note += '{"name":"'+objEmp.Name+'",';
            note += '"title":"'+objEmp.Designation+'"';
        
            employeeProcessed.push(objEmp.Name);
            var empUl = GetOrgJSON(employeeList,objEmp.ID);
            if(empUl !=""){
                note +=',"children": [' + empUl + ']';
            }
            note +='},';
        }       
    } 
    return note;
}
(function($){
  $(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://XXXXXXX/sites/YYYYYYY/_api/web/lists(guid'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')/items?$select=ID,Title,Member/ID,Member/EMail,Member/Title,Manager/ID,Manager/Title,Title&$expand=Manager/Id,Member/Id &$top=1000",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.d.results.length>0){
                var employeeList = [];
                $.each(data.d.results,function(i,employee){
                var Email=employee.Member.EMail;
                    var title = employee.Member.Title;
                    var ID = employee.Member.ID;
                    var manager = employee.Manager.ID!= undefined ? employee.Manager.ID:"0";
                    //var manager = employee.Manager.ID ? employee.Manager.ID : "0";
                    var designation=employee.designation;
                    var objEmp = new Employee(ID,title ,manager,designation,Email);
                    employeeList.push(objEmp);
                });
                var datascource = GetOrgJSON(employeeList,"0").replace(/},]/g,"}]");
                datascource=datascource.slice(0, datascource.length-1);
                
                //$('#chart-container').orgchart({
                //  'data' : JSON.parse(datascource),
                // 'nodeContent': 'title'
                //});
                

                 $('#chart-container').orgchart({
                 'data' : JSON.parse(datascource),
                 'depth': 2,
                 'nodeTitle': 'name',
                 'nodeContent': 'title',
                 'nodeID': 'id',
                 'createNode': function($node, data) {
                 var nodePrompt = $('<i>', {
                 'class': 'fa fa-info-circle second-menu-icon',
                  click: function() {
                $(this).siblings('.second-menu').toggle();
          }
        });
        var secondMenu = '<div class="second-menu"><img class="avatar" src="img/avatar/' + data.id + '.jpg"></div>';
        $node.append(nodePrompt).append(secondMenu);
      }
    });             
                 
                 

                
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //alert("Error");
        }
    });  
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Is the image source `src="img/avatar/' + data.id + '.jpg"` available in your server where your index.html is hosted? Check network tab and see whether there's any request error for image source (may be CORS issue)?
Try creating `img` folder at the level of index.html and dump few images with the corresponding id's and check whether this resolves your issue.

Comment: image source is constructed from sharepoint that is working and images are coming  what am not getting image on hover just like plugin it always shows image at end not same like plugin and image not comes on hover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding below css in your stylesheet, referred from [jQuery Org Chart](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Fully-Customizable-Organisational-Chart-Plugin-With-jQuery-OrgChart/) (by inspecting DOM through browser Dev console)

```css
.orgchart .node .second-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -70px;
    border-radius: 35px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px #999;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: i added the css but toggle is not getting happened on click which make display none and display block

Comment: sorry my bad i was making mistake its working thank you